# My Inputs are behaving unexpectedly when I create a list of inputs in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to do a list of input where users can provide values for each input. I chose to dynamically render this from an array because the items which values needs to be provided for is coming from a backend server and it’s dynamic (changes per user). Right now, I have been able to render the input according to the array but for some reason the inputs are throwing some inconsistent behaviours like when I type in one input the value isn’t consistent.

Here is code:

```
const App = () => {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(['name','age','food','gender'])
  const [state, setState] = useState({})
  
  return(
    <div className="">
      {inputs.map((item)=>(
        <input type="text" value={state[item]} placeholder={item} onChange={e =>{
            setState({...state,[item]:e.target.value })
          }} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have played around with different data types as array values but no improvement. I also tried to just show one static input and that works, but when I switch back to rendering it dynamically the issue occurs again.

Comment: First, do the basics right. Fix that warning about not providing a key to items returned by map function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advice to add the key prop to your list when rendering. In this instance you can use your `item` from your `inputs`, since they are unique

```
{inputs.map((item)=>(
    <input key={item} type="text" value={state[item]} placeholder={item} onChange={e =>{
        setState({...state,[item]:e.target.value })
      }} />
  ))}
```

You can read more about it in this react docs https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists